# Can't use command line – "command not found" after editing PATH

Tags: macos, command-line, .bash-profile, mamp

I'm running OS X Mavericks and was trying to install MAMP PRO 2.2.

I was trying to configure the PATH variable to have the PHP binaries of MAMP PRO. I added the following line on my `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP PRO/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

As you may notice, since I have MAMP PRO and not just MAMP, I've added a *space*. As a consequence, I know have the following error each time I run the *terminal*:

```
-bash: export: `PRO/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin':
not a valid identifier
```

Worst: I can't get any command to run, like: `ls`, `clear` etc. I always get:

> "command not found"

I don't even know the *absolute path* for `ls`. How can I make the commands work again, so that I can properly fix the path I was trying to setup on the `.bash_profile` file?

Answer (score 1):

Got to `~` by entering `cd`, then: `/usr/bin/pico .bash_profile`.

I then removed the *space*, and the *PRO* designation.

So that it stays like this:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

It seems to work now.

Comment: That is, if MAMP really is in the folder `MAMP`. If you need a space, double-quote the path, e.g. `export PATH="/Applications/MAMP PRO/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin":$PATH`